# Book: Actuarial Mathematics for Life Contingent Risks Exercise 2.4

Tags: statistics, actuarial-science

*Exercise $2.4$*  Let $$S_0(x) =\exp\left({-\left( Ax+ \frac{Bx^2}2 +\frac{C(D^x-1)}{\ln D}\right)}\right)$$
where $A, B, C , D>0$

$(b)$ Derive a formula for $S_x(t)$

I know the equation for $S_x(t)= \dfrac{S_0(x+t)}{S_0(x)}$

Right now I am at: $\dfrac{\exp\left({-\left( Ax+ At+\frac{B(x^2+2xt+t^2)}2 +\frac{C(D^{x+t}-1)}{\ln D}\right)}\right)}{\exp\left({-\left( Ax+ \frac{Bx^2}2 +\frac{C(D^x-1)}{\ln D}\right)}\right)}$

Do the $2$ exp's combine to just be a single exp?  I am unsure of how to cancel things out.  Essentially the basic algebra is tripping me up.  Please Help!

Comment: If $a$ and $b$ are real numbers then $\operatorname{exp}(a)/\operatorname{exp}(b) = \operatorname{exp}(a-b)$. Does this help your simplification?

Comment: That does yes!  Now I just have to see what like terms within the parentheses I can make go away lol

Comment: Okay so now I have it simplified to exp [-At - 1/2B(2xt + 2t) - (C/logD)D^t], that seems like a logical answer to me.  Can someone let me know if I am totally off?

Comment: Hint: Pick random numbers for A,B,C and D. Use DESMOS to graph the original expressions and then your result. If the graphs line up, you did it right.

Comment: They are in fact completely different graphs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is better to let $$f(x) = Ax + \frac{Bx^2}{2} + \frac{C(D^x - 1)}{\log D}$$ for fixed constants $A, B, C, D$, then observe $$S_x(t) = \frac{S_0(x+t)}{S_0(x)} = \frac{\exp(-f(x+t))}{\exp(-f(x))} = \exp(-f(x+t)+f(x)).$$  Then $$\begin{align}
f(x) - f(x+t) 
&= \left(Ax - A(x+t)\right) + \left(\frac{Bx^2}{2} - \frac{B(x+t)^2}{2}\right) + \left(\frac{C(D^x - 1)}{\log D} - \frac{C(D^{x+t} - 1)}{\log D}\right) \\
&= -At - \frac{B}{2}\left((x^2 + 2xt + t^2) - x^2\right) - \frac{C}{\log D} \left(D^x D^t - D^x \right) \\
&= -\left( At + \frac{B}{2}t(2x + t) + \frac{C D^x}{\log D}(D^t - 1)\right).
\end{align}$$

Comment: Thank you!  Yeah i messed up and accidentally did 2t instead of t^2 at some point in the problem.

Comment: @rkong If you found the answer useful, please consider accepting the question as answered and/or upvoting it.